# Why is my ProtectedRoutes component broken?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cookies

I am reusing this component from another project, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work in this one despite working in the other one.

It should check if the user has a token in their cookies, and then redirect to the homepage if they don't. If they do, they should see the component.

I'm not receiving any errors. The page always redirects to the homepage.

ProtectedRoutes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();


export default function ProtectedRoutes({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    
    //get the cookie if there is one
    const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

    //if there is a valid cookie, show component, otherwise go to homepage
    return token ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/" />
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from './Components/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './Components/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './Components/RegisterScreen';
import AccountScreen from './Components/AccountScreen';
import PreferencesScreen from './Components/PreferencesScreen';
import ProtectedRoutes from './Components/ProtectedRoutes';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();


function App() {

  const openMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add("open");
  }
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove("open");
  }
  
  const logout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cookies.remove("TOKEN", {path: "/"});
    window.location.href="/"
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <header className="header">
          <div className="brand">
            <button className="sidebar-button" onClick={openMenu}>
              &#9776;
            </button>
            <Link to="/" >Title</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="header-links">
            <Link to="/signin" >Sign In</Link>
            <Link to="/myaccount/" >My Account</Link>
            <Link to="/logout" onClick={(e) => logout()}>Logout</Link>
          </div>
        </header>
        <aside className="sidebar">
          <button className="sidebar-close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>x</button>
          <div className="sidebar-links">
            <h4>New Entry</h4>
            <h4>New Entry</h4>
          </div>
        </aside>
        <main className="main">
          <div className="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
              <Route exact path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen />} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" element={<LoginScreen />} />
              <Route exact path="/myaccount" element={<ProtectedRoutes component={AccountScreen} />} />
              <Route exact path="/preferences" element={<PreferencesScreen />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: so, what is the result? you fail to mention in what way it fails

Comment: I'm so sorry lol I'm very tired. It always redirects to the homepage. Added that to the post.

Comment: Can you `console.log(token)` in ProtectedRoute to confirm that there is indeed a cookie? What is the result?

Comment: It logs undefined.